# How to control a conflicting click event with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML...

```
<div id="panel">
<a class="ext" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

If i have an $(#panel).on({ click: function(e) {...} event which will expand the div height or collapse it, how do it tell the click event to "not fire" if I click on the .ext class item, so that I can go to google.com.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach is to simply test the target of the `click` event:

```
$('#panel').on({
    click: function(e) {
        var target = e.target,
            $target = $(target);
        if ($target.hasClass('ext')) {
            window.location = target.href;
        }
        else if {
            // do whatever you'd normally do for a click on #panel
        }
    });
```

References:

- [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

Comment: This is a better solution if you're supporting < IE9

Comment: @DavidBarker better than.... what? Jason's solution will work in < IE9 just as well.

Comment: @KevinB I may be wrong but my understanding was that e.stopPropagation was only fully supported by IE in 9+

Comment: @David: this is true, but (I'm *pretty sure* that) jQuery normalises it so that it's equally functional cross-browser.

Comment: @David just read up on the jQuery api and yes it does indeed normalise the event object... goes to show you learn something new everyday :-)

Comment: @David: this...could be a confusing read, for later viewers. But I'm glad to have shown you something new! =)

Answer (score 9):

Add this:

```
$('.ext').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

That will prevent the event from bubbling up to the `#panel` element.

Comment: that is the first time I ever used that.  awesome.  thank you!